# jquery : hover and hover (one after another)

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I'm not sure if it's possible like this : I'd like to have one effect when I hover an element, then another effect with a new hover, and so on...

```
$('.suivre').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(50%,0)" }).addClass('suivre2');
    });
$('.suivre2').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(0,50%)" }).addClass('suivre3');
    });
```

I tried with and without addClass. Only the first hover is working.

I also tried with mouseover and had the same result

```
$('.suivre').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(50%,0)" }).addClass('suivre2');
    });
    $('.suivre2').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(0,50%)" }).addClass('suivre3');
    });
```

Maybe, i'd better search for another way.

Thank you @j08691 for the duplicate flag. I did find a solution in it :

```
$('.social').on('mouseover', '.suivre', function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(50%,0)" }).addClass('suivre2').removeClass('suivre');
    });
    $('.social').on('mouseover', '.suivre2', function(){
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate(50%,50px)" }).addClass('suivre3').removeClass('suivre2');
    });
```

Comment: It is very weird and sounds like a bs but when you are adding class make sure that the one u added is being declared in your css after the default one. The order of classes in your css file depends somehow.

Comment: It could be causing conflicts in your css too. Why not remove the previous class and add a new class on hover?

Comment: @StevenDropper it's because the OP is binding hover (or mouseover) to elements that exist when the page loads, not when he adds the suivre2 class. That's what event delegation does.

Comment: @IsabelInc it's because the OP is binding hover (or mouseover) to elements that exist when the page loads, not when he adds the suivre2 class. That's what event delegation does.

Comment: Thats good to know. Thanks @StevenDropper

Comment: @IsabelInc - No problem. I was frustrated trying to figure out what is wrong with my code yet it was the order of classes in css...

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see what you mean.  @j08691

Comment: Thank you all ! @StevenDropper , Isabel Inc : I tried removeClass, but it's not working. j08691 I wiil study the previous post and update you as soon as I can.